# Cannot iterate list inside JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to answer a question using expression language in JSP. I tried some code, but it is not working properly. Can someone please help me ?

**Question -** 
Source = [How to call servlet on jsp page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066367/how-to-call-servlet-on-jsp-page-load)

I want to call a servlet 'latest_products' on load of index.jsp page.This servlet has records in List. I want to pass this List to index.jsp. but i don't want to display the name of servlet in url. is there any way by which i can do this.

Expected output - Heading plus list of three product names.

Actual output - Heading only.

**What I tried -**

Servlet:

```
public class ProductList extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public ProductList() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
        products.add("Car");
        products.add("Gun");
        products.add("Shades");

        request.setAttribute("productsList", products);

    }

}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="blah..."%>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "blah...">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="blah...">
</head>
<body>

<c:import url="/ProductList" />

<c:set var="myProducts" scope="request" value="${param.productsList}"/>

<h1>List of products from servlet</h1>
<c:forEach var="product" items= "${myProducts}" varStatus="i">
${product}<br>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

One small question besides this, why do I get an error `Encountered illegal body of tag "c:set" tag, given its attributes` when I enclose the c:set tag with a `</c:set>` after the `</c:foreach>` tag ? I thought the c:set was like a block of code with a scope. But, it does not seem to be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
<c:set var="myProducts" value="${requestScope.productsList}" />
```

or

```
<c:set var="myProducts" scope="request" value="${productsList}" />
```

instead of

```
<c:set var="myProducts" scope="request" value="${param.productsList}" />
```

to get the attribute value from the request scope. Only request *parameters* are made available in the implicit object `param`. You can't access request *attribute* using the implicit object `param`.

---

> why do I get an error Encountered illegal body of tag `c:set` tag, given its attributes when I enclose the c:set tag with a `</c:set>` after the `</c:foreach>` tag ?

because It's already closed as shown below (look a slash at the end) and there is no opening tag for `c:set`.

```
<c:set var="myProducts" scope="request" value="${param.productsList}"/>
```

---

#### EDIT

`<c:import url="/ProductList" />` or `<jsp:include page="/ProductList" />` are GET requests that will call `doGet()` method of Servlet and that is empty as per your code that's why nothing is shown on the JSP page.

Either call `doPost()` method from the `doGet()` method or provide the implementation of `doGet()` method as well.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I forgot to mention, even when there was no slash at end of opening tag of c:set, i was still getting that error. I wonder why. So, this c:set thing is not like a block of code with variable scope ?

Comment: because `c:set` doesn't supports any body. It says `Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator - illegal body of tag "c:set" tag`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, param comes from an html form. My bad. But, I used both the methods you gave and i still don't get my list of products. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: It's working fine for me. Let me share you the code.

Comment: Sometimes, my output does not even change after republishing to tomcat, restarting and cleaning. To be safe, I'll just close and restart eclipse. Sometimes, things start working after that.

Comment: Sounds good. I am also using Eclipse then there is no need to restart the tomcat server. I made the changes in the JSP and simply refresh the page.

Comment: Restarted eclipse. No change same old blank output.

Comment: Is *List of products from servlet* displayed on the page? Try `<c:out value="Length : ${myProducts.size() }"/>` before `c:forEach` or post the actual code as EDIT in your question itself.

Comment: It's a GET request and you have given implementation of POST only. call ``doPost()` from `doGet()` or provide the logic in `doGet()` itself.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my question. It is mostly the same as before. I don't know why I can't make it work.

Comment: Got it. Can't I make it a POST request instead of GET ?

Comment: Look at 2nd comments for your last question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066367/how-to-call-servlet-on-jsp-page-load)

Comment: Thanks for all the help Braj. I appreciate it very much. I like you. It is a very nice to have meet you. Chenqui.