# Get method when page loading in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want when my page such as `index.jsp` loading(calling get method) send data for `index.jsp` page such as title. I checked this question but this question solution([How to call servlet on jsp page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066367/how-to-call-servlet-on-jsp-page-load)) has error in my web application.

This my `index.jsp` page code(I want send title from `changeTitle.java` class):

```
<title><c:import url="/sysAdmin/changeTitle.java" /> 
<c:out value="${message }"></c:out></title>
```

This my `changeTitle.java` class get method:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setAttribute("message", "hello");
}
```

And I don't know how addressing to class in `index.jsp` of my project and bellow is my project directories:

[image]

Comment: "*has error in my web application.*" What is that? The request attribute `message` would not be available in the target resources (the JSP page), if you redirected the request instead of forwarding/dispatching it. What is the rest of the code in the `doGet()` method?

Comment: I want this page every time load, title set from sent message from class

Comment: Taken. How do you reach the JSP page from your Servlet class (and how is your Servlet mapped to the JSP page)? Do you redirect the request to the JSP page or dispatch/forward the request to it (or you do nothing)?

Comment: I do nothing!! and I want just send message!

Comment: Really? It is hard to believe that you are doing nothing. Anyway you need to dispatch the request to the target JSP page such as `request.getRequestDispatcher("/path/to/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);` (it is basically the last line in your `doGet()` method). Consider changing the path according to the JSP page location. Make sure that you appropriately mapped the Servlet to your desired JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the response, not the request

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setAttribute("message", "hello");
}
```

Comment: This not my purpose, My purpose set title to setted value in changeTitle.java class no method name!

Comment: response don't have such method

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
<c:out value="<%=request.getAttribute('message')%>">
```